# Core Data iCloud sync or smth else?

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, synchronization, data-synchronization

I build an iOS app which works with base. User can work with it everywhere, that is cool. When application starts for the first time, obviously, base will be empty. For now, user's base stores data locally with Core Data. But there is a case, when user may have his own base with a lot of data and he do not want to start work from scratch. For this reason I want to create simple Cocoa App for macOS, which will allow user to import some data from, for example - CSV file. 
Both Core Data models (iOS app and macOS app) will be the same. I just want to make sync between two platforms. 
I think it's possible with cloudKit, but which way is the best? Core Data Sync or smth like supporting MySQL database on server, etc...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Asking which method is "best" is a matter of opinion, but in mine, Apple has made working with iCloud fairly simple. If all you want to do is sync between platforms, I would use cloudKit. There seems to be no reason to spin up your own MYSQL database instance and introduce another level of complexity, when the functionality you're looking for is free and easily accessible.

See this WWDC16 video for some cloudKit tips: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/226/